# Format datetime and return datetime python (no intermediary string step)

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, python-datetime

I have a datetime data type and I want to format **keeping it as datetime data type** but I could just find how to do if I do `datetime-> string-> datetime` and I want to do directly `datetime->datetime`. Is this possible?

This is my code:

```
from datetime import datetime

start_date = datetime.now()
res = datetime.strptime(start_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ"), "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
```

Comment: could you clarify what you mean by "*I want to format keeping it as datetime*"? Note that datetime objects do not have a *format* like e.g. a string can have. They're data structures to hold date and time information. And they have a `__str__` method which is called when you print them, that shows the stored date/time in a certain format.

Comment: I also noted you have `Z` in your formatting directive; if you want a datetime object that represents UTC, use `datetime.now(timezone.utc)` (after importing the `timezone` class from the datetime module).

Comment: Hi MrFuppes! On my solution I am passing to string and then converting back to datetime. I was wondering if is possible to get a datetime object and convert to datetime directly without passing as string. Like a datetime.format(string) that returns a datetime; About the "Z" I cannot change, is a directive of the contract to have like this since my original date is like this: 2020-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00Z and I want the %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ format :)

Comment: so you get date/time from some API, as datatype string? If so, changing the datatype would require changing the API, no?

Comment: Actually I get the date/time from a library as a datetime format. Then I want to transform this datetime format I receive from the API to another datetime format and pass to another API. I cannot change the API

Comment: you mean you get a datetime object, i.e. datetime *data type*? and the other API, what does i expect? string? datetime object?

Comment: Exactly, I have a datetime data type as input on the format "2020-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00Z" and I need to return a datetime data type on the format "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ". I do not need to return a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can gain some convenience by using datetime's isoformat methods:

```
from datetime import datetime

# input date/time as string
s = "2020-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00Z"

# to datetime object
# we can strip Z (zulu) since Python treats +00:00 as UTC already
dtobj = datetime.fromisoformat(s.strip('Z'))

print(repr(dtobj))
# datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)

# back to string, format as input
# add the Z since this is not supported in Python by default
s_out = dtobj.isoformat(timespec='milliseconds') + 'Z'

print(s_out)
# 2020-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00Z
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but on my case your "s" variable is a datetime on that format you have written. I want to convert the "s" variable that is a datetime to the format "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ" returning a datetime. But as I am receiving the "s" variable as a datetime and I have to return a datetime I do not want to convert to string because it do not makes sense to me

Comment: @CatarinaNogueira so what you get is a datetime object like `dtobj` in my example. It has UTC specified (Z/zulu). But it has no *format*; see my first comment on the question. We'll have to be precise with the wording to know what we're talking about ;-) If that is expected by the API you're passing the data to, you don't have to do anything since you cannot change any format (just attributes, like e.g. tzinfo).

Comment: Hello again! Thank you for your time on answering. Got it now :)))